# Python 2.6.6 When I get html Source from Website It gives Error

Tags: python-2.7

`Python 2.6.6` When I get `HTML` Source from Website It gives Error but it works on 3 version

```
import urllib
link='https://www.bookabach.co.nz/baches-and-holiday-homes/view/38781/'
f=urllib.urlopen(link)
```

Error as:

> Traceback (most recent call last):
>    File "", line 1,
>   in 
>       f=urllib.urlopen(link)
>    File "E:\Python26\lib\urllib.py", line 86, in urlopen
>       return opener.open(url)
>    File "E:\Python26\lib\urllib.py", line 207, in open
>       return getattr(self, name)(url)
>    File "E:\Python26\lib\urllib.py", line 441, in open_https
>       h.endheaders()
>    File "E:\Python26\lib\httplib.py", line 908, in endheaders
>       self._send_output()
>    File "E:\Python26\lib\httplib.py", line 780, in _send_output
>       self.send(msg)
>    File "E:\Python26\lib\httplib.py", line 739, in send
>       self.connect()
>    File "E:\Python26\lib\httplib.py", line 1116, in connect
>       self.sock = ssl.wrap_socket(sock, self.key_file, self.cert_file)
>    File "E:\Python26\lib\ssl.py", line 338, in
>   wrap_socket
>       suppress_ragged_eofs=suppress_ragged_eofs)
>    File "E:\Python26\lib\ssl.py", line 120, in **init**
>       self.do_handshake()
>    File "E:\Python26\lib\ssl.py", line 279, in do_handshake
>       self._sslobj.do_handshake()
>  IOError: [Errno socket error] [Errno 1] _ssl.c:490: error:1407742E:SSL
>   routines:SSL23_GET_SERVER_HELLO:tlsv1 alert protocol version

Comment: First of all, just out of curiosity, why such an early version of python? Also, why not just use the requests library instead?

Comment: Because I run Script on linux dedicated Server and python version is 2.6.6.

Comment: Requests library should be able to run on 2.6.6. The website says Python >=2.6

Answer (score 0):

You may just need to disable SSL verification as you're attempting to reach the site over HTTPS.

Similar issue solved [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45773648/10289764) with urllib.